# Variance of the sample estimator for two bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X_i$ and $Y_i$, $i=1,2,\cdots,N$ are the two i.i.d. Bernoulli random process with parameters $p_1$ and $p_2$, respectively. A random variable defined as $m_{xy}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_iY_i$. What is the variance of this random variable? If anyone knows the answer, please give me some steps or point out a reference. Thanks in advance.

The Isserlis theorem says,
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X_iX_jY_iY_j]=\mathbb{E}[X_iX_j]\mathbb{E}[Y_iY_j]+\mathbb{E}[X_iY_i]\mathbb{E}[X_iY_j]+\mathbb{E}[X_iY_j]\mathbb{E}[X_jY_i]
\end{equation}
Using the theorem for the above case, I get for $i=j$
\begin{equation}
  p_1p_2+p_1^2p_2^2+p_1^2p_2^2~.
\end{equation}
Similarly, for $i \neq j$, we may have
\begin{equation}
  p_1^2p_2^2+p_1^2p_2^2+p_1^2p_2^2~.
\end{equation}
Is this true? Please point out my mistake, if any. Thank you.

Comment: You original sum, $\sum_{i=1}^N X_i Y_i$ considers only $\{X_{i}Y_{i}\}_{i=1}^N$, pairs where $i = j$, if you are interested in any possible pair then your original sum should be $\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^NX_iY_j$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
Var( \frac{1}{N}\sum X_i Y_i ) = \frac{1}{N}(\mathbb{E}[X_i^2Y_i^2] - \mathbb{E}^2[X_iY_i]),
$$
due to their independence
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_i^2Y_i^2]=\mathbb{E}[X_i^2]\mathbb{E}[Y_i^2]=p_1 p_2
$$
and 
$$
\mathbb{E}^2[X_iY_i] = p_1^2p_2^2 
$$

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I will let you know how I tried using Isserlis' theorem and have not gotten the answer. Thanks once again V. Vancak

Comment: I have added a text in the above question Vancak. Kindly point out my error if there is any. I could not figure out. Thanks. Or Isserlis theorem is only for Gaussian?